# I wanted to save two values in this.props.onChange but only is saving the last

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using a Table from Ant.Design and has two column with inputs.. I wanted to save the two values from this inputs, but just saving the last one.

My columns:

```
<Column
  title="Wanted"
  className="text-center"
  render={this.renderInput('Wanted')}
/>

<Column
  title="Offered"
  className="text-center"
  render={this.renderInput('Offered')}
/>
```

The renderInput function:

```
renderInput = (id) => (text, record) => (
    <Input
      name={record.key}
      data-id={id}
      onChange={e=>this.handleChangeSinglePost(record.key, e.target.value, id)}
    />
  );
```

And the handleChangeSinglePost function:

```
handleChangeSinglePost(name, value, id){
  this.props.onChange(
    {
      ...this.props.value,
      [name]: {
        id: id,
        value: value
      }
    }
  );
 }
```

My console return this:

[image]

But i need something like this:

```
salario-direto:
id: "Wanted"
value: "1"
id: "Offered"
value: "2"
```

Or save two values, but in this way just saving the last one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overriding the value in

```
this.props.onChange(
    {
      ...this.props.value,
      [name]: {
        id: id,
        value: value
      }
    }
  );
```

because both itens have the same name.
When you use `[name]` you override the last value that had the name `salario-direto`

If you want something like this

```
salario-direto:
id: "Wanted"
value: "1"
id: "Offered"
value: "2"
```

You need to use a Array to store it.
I'm not sure how you need to send the data but i think is something like this ...?

```
salario-direto: [
    {
        id: "Wanted"
        value: "1"
    },
    {
        id: "Offered"
        value: "2"
    }
]
```

**IF** this is the case you need, on the `onChange` you need to do this:

```
this.props.onChange(
    {
      [name]: this.props.value[name].concat({
        id: id,
        value: value
      })
    }
  );
```

Comment: Yes, i need something like you writed

Comment: what do you have in `...this.props.value` ? is the other `salario-direto` or is more information?

Comment: I has the `salario-direto`

Comment: Thanks, you saved my life!